# Can't start emulator with command line using ssh server

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

So, I have this server that is designated as a device for automation test things. To access the server I'm using ssh most of the time or using screen mirroring to debug my machine. I want to start the emulator in my server from my local using ssh but it failed, showing this error:

```
user@msb-10-r2u32-2u4n-b:~$ emulator @PH_nightly_10

INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.13.0 (build_id 9189900) (CL:N/A)emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /home/user/android_sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/

INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.

WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.

INFO    | Warning: could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))

INFO    | Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/user/android_sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" even though it was found. ((null):0, (null))

Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.((null):0, (null))INFO    | Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.((null):0, (null))
```

But, when I tried using screen mirroring (noMachine) and wrote the same command from its terminal, it was succeeded to start the emulator.

I tried running headless with this command

```
$ emulator -no-window @EMULATOR_ID
```

It succeeded with this logs:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.13.0 (build_id 9189900) (CL:N/A)

emulator: INFO: Found systemPath /home/bukalapak/android_sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/

INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.

WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.

WARNING | cannot add library /home/bukalapak/android_sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed

INFO    | added library /home/bukalapak/android_sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so

INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz

pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextCould not init \`pa' audio driver

WARNING | \*\*\* No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.\*\*\*

INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none

INFO    | Advertising in: /run/user/1001/avd/running/pid_24535.ini

INFO    | setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2160 dpiX 440 dpiY 440

INFO    | Cold boot: incompatible snapshot version

INFO    | Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:

 - Start Android Studio

 - Select menu "Tools \> Android \> SDK Manager"

 - Click "SDK Tools" tab

 - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox

 - Click "OK"

INFO    | boot completed

INFO    | boot time 26691 ms

INFO    | Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.

INFO    | Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
```

Answer (score 0):

After a day of messing around, I found a fix that worked for me. Also, I believe the server machine has to have a display plugged in for this to work.

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

The main reason your emulator is not starting is that it has no display to start it on when you use ssh. Running ssh with -X flag will start it locally.